# How to install Rtl8723de driver in 18.04 without internet?

Tags: 18.04

I can't use wifi and it shows me no Wi-Fi adapter found.
I have searched many answers and I've seen all of the answers tell me to connect to a wired connection and download from github. But I don't have wired connection.
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot use Wifi, nor Ethernet. There are not much more possibilities. Maybe try to download file on another computer, move it on USB, and then plug into your computer.

Comment: Among other things, having a spare USB wifi dongle or USB ethernet adapter can be useful